# Making a 2D array without brackets

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a 2D array, but it prints out in one row and with brackets.

How do I make it into rows and columns without brackets?

```
rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows: "))


board = [[i + (j * cols) for i in range(1, cols + 1)] for j in range(0, rows)]

print(board)
```

Comment: what do you mean without brackets?

Comment: You're printing a list so there will always be brackets. If you'd like to print out each row you should loop through each row and print. for row in board:  print(row)

Answer (score 2):

```
for row in board:
    print(" ".join(list(map(str, row))))
```

We iterate through the board and for each row, make it a list of strings (using `map`) instead of numbers and join them with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows: "))
cols=rows#my thing would not run without this line 

board = [[i + (j * cols) for i in range(1, cols + 1)] for j in range(0, rows)]

print(board)
arr=[]
for i in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        print(str(i)+" "+str(board[i][c]))
```

Output:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
1 10
2 11
2 12
2 13
2 14
2 15
3 16
3 17
3 18
3 19
3 20
4 21
4 22
4 23
4 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
for row in board:
   print(row)
```